# What do "strike out" and "hit 60 home runs" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does this sentence "Buffett said that Dimon should be expected to **strike out** every now and then, just as Ruth did in the year he **hit 60 home runs**." mean "Sometimes Dimon should also be criticized like Ruth in the year Ruth succeeded"?

source: http://money.cnn.com/2016/09/21/investing/warren-Buffett-wells-fargo-jpmorgan-chase/index.html?iid=SF_LN

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Criticised? No. I'd put it the other way:

> Dimon should still be *applauded* despite mistakes, like Ruth in the year Ruth succeeded.

Everyone makes mistakes, so if their successes outweigh their mistakes then don't concentrate on their mistakes!

Comment: Yes, but does @haile understand that the terms he/she asks about are baseball terms?